# "local and global" SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does the function `openFehBgQ` not like the two instructions marked Comments 1 & 2?

Comment 1 tries to update the `fehCurrent`, which is declared `global`, but produces the following error:

```
      SyntaxError: name 'fehCurrent' is local and global ;
```

Comment 2 does not work at all, although `timeKill` is remembered for the `time.sleep` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import glob, subprocess, time, os

def globalVariables():
    global fehCurrent # Title (str) of current 'Child' window
    global fehNew # Title (str) of new 'Child' window
    global fehWindow # Data (array) for current 'Child' window
    global timeKill
    global timeZero


# Data (array) for current 'Child' window
fehBg = ['fehBg', '-g', '%ux%u+%u+%u' % (320, 240,  
    50,50), '-x', 'Media/Bg.jpg']
fehCurrent = 'fehq1'    # Title (str) of current 'Child' window

def openFehBgQ():
    if fehCurrent != fehNew:
        subprocess.Popen(fehWindow)
        time.sleep(timeKill)
        os.popen('%s%s' % ('pkill ', fehCurrent))
        # fehCurrent = fehNew    # See Comment 1
        timeElapsed = 0
        # timeZero = time.time()    # See Comment 2

fehNew = "fehBg"
fehWindow = fehBg
openFehBgQ() 
print "1_", fehCurrent
fehCurrent = fehNew
print "2_", fehCurrent
timeZero = time.time()
```

Comment: two things you don't want to be doing, using global and using os.popen,  if you are using python3 then your print's are going to cause a syntax error. print is a function in python3 as opposed to a statement in python2 so you need parens `print( "1_", fehCurrent)`

Comment: *"Why does the Function def openFehBgQ..."* - please read [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Exactly what version of Python are you using to run this?

Comment: You can also `p = subprocess.Popen(fehWindow)` and use `p.kill()` to kill the process later.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Am using Python3.2.3. However, it is not the print function causing the error but the fehCurrent = fehNew   within the openFehBgQ(): .

Comment: @jonrsharpe What error(s) in the Style Guide have I contravened ?

Comment: @walter1957 why not read it and find out?

Comment: @walter1957, your code has no syntax errors beyond that, there are a few NameErrors but no SyntaxErrors and you never actually assign values to `timeKill` etc..

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have looked at it and noted that, as in all forms of grammar, there are numerous exceptions/options/etc that holes can be picked in anyones code layout.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Correct about the timeKill in my snippet of code but in the working code it was 2 secs;

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Concerning the p.kill() instruction I want to open a new 'child' window first & then close the old one that is now behind it. This avoids a blank screen while the new 'child' window is loaded. For this reason I have multiple copies of feh in the /usr/bin/ each with a name associated with each image - fehBg, fehq1, etc. If I did not, at the end of the day there would be thousands of 'child' windows open.

Comment: @walter1957 given that there is only one thing happening in the snippet I posted, I thought you'd have put it together! Your function name is neither compliant with the guidance (`lowercase_with_underscores`) nor, more importantly, particularly useful (especially as you don't have docstrings to explain what exactly `openFehBgQ` *means*).

Comment: @jonrsharpe ◾  mixedCase  (differs from CapitalizedWords by initial lowercase character!)  The Guidance allows this. I asked a specific question about one part of my working code so do not think it necessary to include all the code.

Comment: @walter1957 yes, albeit strictly *"only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style"*. The list under **Descriptive: Naming Styles** only provides a list of examples of naming styles; they aren't all considered acceptable in Python. And, again, my point is more that the name isn't *meaningful* - even if it makes perfect sense in context, it's difficult to provide helpful suggestions when we don't understand what the code is trying to do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I found the other Contributors comments much more informative than yours will ever be. The list under Descriptive: Naming Styles is within the Python Style Guide so keep your semantics out of any Forums & answer the specific question(s) posed.

Comment: @walter1957 although you are correct that the list is *"within the Python Style Guide"*, it is there merely to enumerate the different styles that exist (to quote the guide: *"There are a lot of different naming styles. It helps to be able to recognize what naming style is being used, independently from what they are used for."*). Should you find my (or any other) comments un- (or insufficiently) informative, do feel free to ignore them. *"keep your semantics out of any Forums"* - this isn't a forum. *"answer the specific question(s) posed"* - these are comments, not answers.

Comment: BTW, this question has much more code than the minimum amount needed to produce the error. In the future, try to follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @walter1957, ...by the way, jonrsharpe is a well-known user who's consistently helpful within the Python tag. Going out of your way to antagonize folks -- particularly folks who are trying to help you ask better questions in the future, which will help you get better/faster answers and fewer downvotes -- doesn't seem like a way to make a good first impression.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks for your comments. I had to insert  global fehCurrent    before    if fehCurrent != fehNew:   to get the SyntaxError message.

Comment: Indeed -- that's not what I was referring to re: excess code. You could remove all reference to the `subprocess` and `os` modules (actually, `time` and `glob` as well), remove all global variables other than `fehCurrent`, and have a much shorter reproducer with fewer conflating factors.

Answer (score 1):

The `global` statement tells Python's interpreter that a given variable name refers to a global variable, rather than a local one. You only need to use it if you're going to assign to the variable. If you only access its existing value, you don't need to make a `global` declaration.

You're getting an error in `openFehBG` because you're accessing a variable `fehCurrrent`, then later trying to assign that same name, which, by default would create a local variable. This sort of out-of-order access is not allowed. You need a `global` statement in there to make the lookup and assignment both refer to the global variable.

That said, using global variables, with or without `global` statements is usually a symptom of bad design. You should pass arguments to your functions, and save their return values instead of having lots of globals to keep track of.

Comment: While your explanation is correct, this would usually just result in an `UnboundLocalError`. OP’s syntax error is confusing me here though.

Comment: @Blcknght So in the def openFehBgQ(): have a line var=fehNew then outside the function have fehCurrent=var ?

Comment: @Blcknght I inserted global fehTemp before if fehCurrent != fehNew: and return fehTemp at the end of def openFehBgQ(): to transfer the variable.

Comment: Thanks @Blcknght . Have removed all references to globals and passing & returning all values as you descibed in your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The version that works as expected with the minimum number of lines would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

fehCurrent = "fehQ1"

def open_feh_bg(fehCurrent, fehNew):
    if fehCurrent != fehNew:
        timeZero = time.time()
        return timeZero

fehNew = "fehBg"
open_feh_bg(fehCurrent, fehNew) 
fehCurrent = fehNew
```

Thanks for your help.